# Can't reference NuGet Packages IN ASP.NET Core Application in F# .fs file

Tags: asp.net, f#

When using the open command I can only access .NET Framework namespaces in the .fs file.  A C# .cs file can access the desired namespaces within the project using the 'using' command.  What do I need to do to reference those namespaces in F#

Comment: Make sure the project actually has the right reference added. Also, don't expect the same user experience if you are using ReSharper with C#. You might have to rebuild 'manually' between changes to your lib code you are referencing.

Comment: The dnx libraries I'm trying to reference are in the project but they're not showing up in the .fs file in the .cs file they show up